# VBA: How to replace (For...Each) With (Array)?

Tags: excel, vba

**Main Module**

My code is working fine, the idea is to lock the entire row in the target workbook if source workbook cells in column b have a yellow color....

The question is how to replace the for-each loop with arrays for performance-wise, that's all?

```
  Sub LockYellow()
    
    
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    .Unprotect "007"
    .UsedRange.Locked = False
    .Range("a1:z1").Locked = True
    End With
    
    ' ---## Global
        Dim SourceBook As Workbook
        Set SourceBook = GetWorkbook(Source)
    
        
        
        Dim X, xrange As Range
        Set xrange = SourceBook.Worksheets("Data").Range("b2:b1499")
        
        For Each X In xrange
        
        'If X.Interior.Color = 65535 Then
      If X.value = "User_1" Then
        Dim u As String
        u = X.Address
        'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range(u).Value2 = SourceBook.Worksheets("Data").Range(u).Value2
        'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range(u).Interior.Color = 65535
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range(u).EntireRow.Locked = True
        End If
        Next X


       If Not SourceBook Is Nothing Then
           SourceBook.Close savechanges:=False
    End If
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Protect "007"
    
    
    End Sub
```

**Helper Module**

```
  Public Const Source As String = "C:\Users\vv\Desktop\Sourcesheet.xlsx"

    Public Function GetWorkbook(ByVal sFullName As String) As Workbook
    
        Dim sFile As String
        Dim wbReturn As Workbook
    
        sFile = Dir(sFullName)
    
        On Error Resume Next
            Set wbReturn = Workbooks(sFile)
    
            If wbReturn Is Nothing Then
                Set wbReturn = Workbooks.Open(sFullName)
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    
        Set GetWorkbook = wbReturn
    
    End Function
```

Comment: I don't think an array is going to help you here.

Comment: @Bigben is it a dead-end? no other alternatives?

Comment: Maybe `Union` but I haven't tested it.

Comment: What if I changed the logic from color to value, meaning that instead of checking the yellow color in the source sheet it will check a value i.e. "User_1". \then get the address, then lock the same entirerow address in target sheet.

Comment: That might be slightly faster.

Comment: @bigben I have edited my post, to search for a value instead, would that be okay to turn it to an array? I am not good at arrays, I need some help!

Comment: You may be able to use `Range.AutoFilter` and `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` here.

Comment: @BigBen but let's say I have 50K records and 49K have "User_1" as a value inside and the other 1K records have various other values, then using SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) may lead to the same runtime because it represents a larger range that would take more time. I just do not want to manipulate the for...loop solution, that's why I was thinking arrays, but anyways thanks for your time and help I appreciated alot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

Dim test as Range
Set test = SourceBook.Worksheets("Data").Range("b2:b1499")

Dim v As Variant
v = test.Value
    
Dim x as Long, rowLock as Range
For x = lbound(v) to ubound(v)
    
    If v(x,1) = "User_1"
        If rowLock is Nothing Then
           Set rowLock = ws.cells(x+1,test.column) 'x + 1 because range starts at row 2
        Else 
           Set rowLock = Union(rowLock,ws.cells(x+1,test.column))
        End If
    End If
Next

If not rowLock is Nothing Then rowLock.EntireRow.Locked = True
```

Comment: Thanks a million :D